# .NET - FindIndex() compile error from Extended List class

Tags: c#, .net, collections

In .Net/C# I have a class that's derived from List.  When I try to use the FindNextIndex member of that derived class, I get compile errors like below.

Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Predicate'

Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.FindIndex(System.Predicate)' has some invalid arguments

Some simplified code is below.

```
class CTileBag:List<int>
{
    ...
}
```

Then later I try to use it in another class

```
CTileBag c = new CTileBag();
int idx = c.FindIndex(IsSwamp);
```

And IsSwamp is defined in the class I'm using CTile bag in as

```
private static bool IsSwamp(TerrainType type)
        {
            if (type == TerrainType.TT_FUNGUS_SWAMP)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your predicate takes a `TerrainType`, but your list is a `List<int>`. The predicate type depends on the list type. It sounds like your tile bag should *actually* be a `List<TerrainType>`, at which point it should work.

However:

- I would generally suggest *not* deriving from `List<int>`. Prefer composition over inheritance - I suspect it would be better to make your tile bag type *contain* a `List<T>`.
- Follow .NET naming conventions: don't prefix your classes with `C`, and make your enum values just PascalCased, like `FungusSwamp` instead of `TT_FUNGUS_SWAMP`.
- Your method body can be simplified to just:

  ```
  return type == TerrainType.FungusSwamp;
  ```

Comment: Yeah, I originally did have it contain a list class but was running into the same issue. So I did the inheritance as a way to potentially get around my issue. That didn't work either probably due to what you say. I'll give it a shot.  And regarding .net naming conventions, I'm a C++ programmer falling back on those habits - it's hard to get all the little nicities in all at once.

Comment: @DanG: I find that it's worth trying to dive into naming conventions as hard as possible - painful as it can undoubtedly be - as that keeps reminding you that you're *not* writing your more familiar language; it helps to stop you from falling into the idioms of that language, and basically writing (in this case) C# with a C++ accent.